# @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) as PK not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a oracle table with some values inserted and I'm trying to insert one more but when I try to insert this is inserting with id = 0 and then fail because of pk restriction.
This is the table :

```
    CREATE TABLE NPRO_PERFILES_USUARIOS_PRUEBA 
(
  ID_PERFIL NUMBER(9, 0) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY INCREMENT BY 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 MINVALUE 1 CACHE 20 NOT NULL 
, ID_USUARIO NUMBER(9, 0) NOT NULL 
, ID_PANTALLA NUMBER(9, 0) NOT NULL 
, ID_ROL NUMBER(9, 0) NOT NULL 
, FECHA_MODIF DATE 
, USUARIO_MODIF NUMBER(9, 0) 
, ACTIVO VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, CONSTRAINT NPRO_PERFILES_USUARIOS_PRUEBA_PK PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    ID_PERFIL 

 )
```

And this is the class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NPRO_PERFILES_USUARIOS_PRUEBA")
public class Perfil {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id_perfil;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario")
    private User usuario;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_rol")
    private Role role;  

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_pantalla")
    private Pantalla pantalla;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_modif")
    private User usuario_modif;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    private LocalDate fecha_modif;

    private String activo;
}
```

Any idea why is not generating a different id in order to be able to insert?

Regards

Comment: please post the error

Comment: Hi , the error is violation of PK

Comment: It's already solved, I added the values on the table without the id in order to it generate the "secuence" and also I changed the Dialect to :
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect